# Is it possible to configure Oracle session/connection to automatically uppercase strings?

Tags: oracle

Does anyone know if it's possible to configure an Oracle session or connection so that every string that gets persisted is automatically uppercased?

For example, if I invoke a SQL like this: "INSERT INTO STUDENT (name) VALUES ('john doe')"

The information in my table would be persisted like this:

```
STUDENT
--------------------
ID   | 1
NAME | JOHN DOE
```

I've checked this entry but couldn't find anything like this: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch3globenv.htm#sthref186

Thanks!

Comment: [ask tom](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:16370675423662) short answer for 9.x no 10g+ yes.. kinda...  alter session set nls_comp=ansi;
alter session set nls_sort=binary_ci;

Answer (score 5):

There is no session-level configuration parameter for that, no.

You could write a trigger on the `STUDENT` table that would automatically store the data in uppercase but you'd need to do that for every table.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_student
  BEFORE INSERT ON student
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  :new.name := upper( :new.name );
END;
```

Depending on the problem you are trying to solve, you could potentially set your session's NLS settings to ignore case sensitivity so that the string 'John Doe`is considered to be equal to the string`JOHN DOE`.  The options, limitations, and downsides to this will vary with the specific version of Oracle.